# Why are odd-sized fread requests split in two?

Tags: winapi, fread

I noticed that on Windows every time I issue an unbuffered fread() request with an odd length, it's split into 2 requests (as observed through procmon):

a) fread for my requested length-1

b) 2-byte fread for the last byte

This has an obvious performance overhead like 2 kernel requests instead of one etc.

Sample code ran on Windows 10:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* pFile;
    char* buffer;

    pFile = fopen(argv[0], "rb");

    setbuf(pFile, nullptr);

    size_t len = 3;
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);

    if (len != fread(buffer, 1, len, pFile)) { fputs("Reading error", stderr); exit(3); }

    free(buffer);
    fclose(pFile);
    return 0;
}
```

This results in the following procmon reported calls:

ReadFile c:\work\cpptry\Debug\cpptry.exe   SUCCESS   Offset: 0, Length: 2, Priority: Normal

ReadFile c:\work\cpptry\Debug\cpptry.exe   SUCCESS   Offset: 2, Length: 2

It seems as if Windows is incapable of issuing odd-sized requests to the file system. 
What's up with that?

Comment: the `fread` - is *crt* function. internal it call `ReadFile` or `NtReadFile`. this apis of course only once enter kernel with exactly length to read, which you pass. if you view 2 requests to kernel - this mean that `fread`  implementation twice call `[Nt]ReadFile`. anyway this not windows but crt implementation. for test this exactly - set in debugger breakpoint to `NtReadFile`, before `fread` call and look - are it called 1 or 2 time during single `fread`

Comment: *code run on Windows 10* - absolute no matter on which windows version you run. matter which crt version you use. task in crt only, not in windows

Comment: @rbm: The CRT (UCRT) is part of Windows, starting with Windows 10. Depending on the OS you are running, it does make a difference, which CRT you are using.

Answer (score 2):

This is implementation artifact.

MS CRT keeps all `FILE`s buffered even if you tell it to don't do this. Instead file buffer is set to internal buffer with space for two bytes. This allows to keep one code path instead of two and simplifies implementation of fast path in `fgetc` and `fputc`.

```
#define fgetc(_stream) (--(_stream)->_cnt >= 0 ? 0xff & *(_stream)->_ptr++ : _filbuf(_stream))
```

Some of you are probably bothered by size of the buffer (2 bytes when quasi unbuffered), but in `_fread_nolock_s` function we can find optimization
witch tries to read multiplies of buffer size directly to the destination bypassing file buffer.

See `fread.c` in CRT sources:

```
/* calc chars to read -- (count/streambufsize) * streambufsize */
nbytes = (unsigned)(count - count % streambufsize);
...
nread = _read_nolock(_fileno(stream), data, nbytes);
```

Because the file buffer's size is equal 2, even number of bytes is read directly to the destination and eventual one byte goes through the file buffer. Sometimes there could be some bytes in the buffer that need to be transfered to destination before optimized read can take place.

Bonus: buffer size is always forced to multiple of 2.

See `setvbuf.c`:

```
/*
 * force size to be even by masking down to the nearest multiple
 * of 2
 */
size &= (size_t)~1;
...
/*
 * CASE 1: No Buffering.
 */
if (type & _IONBF) {
        stream->_flag |= _IONBF;
        buffer = (char *)&(stream->_charbuf);
        size = 2;
}
```

Code snippets above are from VC 2013 CRT.

For comparison snippets from Universal CRT 10.0.17134

`read.cpp`

```
unsigned const bytes_to_read = stream_buffer_size != 0
    ? static_cast<unsigned>(maximum_bytes_to_read - maximum_bytes_to_read % stream_buffer_size)
    : maximum_bytes_to_read;
...
int const bytes_read = _read_nolock(_fileno(stream.public_stream()), data, bytes_to_read);
```

`setvbuf.cpp`

```
// Force the buffer size to be even by masking the low order bit:
size_t const usable_buffer_size = buffer_size_in_bytes & ~static_cast<size_t>(1);
...
// Case 1:  No buffering:
if (type & _IONBF)
{
    return set_buffer(stream, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&stream->_charbuf), 2, _IOBUFFER_NONE);
}
```

And snippets from VC 6.0 (1998)

`read.c`

```
/* calc chars to read -- (count/bufsize) * bufsize */
nbytes = ( bufsize ? (count - count % bufsize) : count );
nread = _read(_fileno(stream), data, nbytes);
```

`setvbuf.c`

```
/*
 * force size to be even by masking down to the nearest multiple
 * of 2
 */
size &= (size_t)~1;
...
/*
 * CASE 1: No Buffering.
 */
if (type & _IONBF) {
    stream->_flag |= _IONBF;
    buffer = (char *)&(stream->_charbuf);
    size = 2;
}
```

Comment: "This allows to keep one code path instead of two" ... so saved a couple of lines of code to double the overhead for small IOs! Don't mean to be rude but that's a textbook example of a crappy implementation. This forces users to bypass the crt implementation altogether and go directly to ReadFile defeating its purpose.

Comment: Presumably, this depends on the version of Visual Studio you are using. Starting with VS 2015, the CRT has been refactored, and is now part of Windows starting with Windows 10. I wasn't able to find the implementation files on my VS 2017 installation either, so things may or may not be as written in this answer.

Comment: @Alf You have left out part after **and**. Actually this code optimizes typical operations. `fgetc` has reduced ReadFile calls by half, `fgets` benefits also a lot. It will lose for many small reads (> 2 bytes), but this is the case for witch buffered I/O was invented so allow library to optimize your use case.

Comment: @IInspectable Original snippets were from VC 2013 CRT. I have added snippets from Universal CRT 10.0.17134 and VC 6.0. There are some tweaks, but overall picture is still the same.

Comment: @DanielSęk Unfortunately you are missing one typical use case. Larger binary IOs that don't need any buffering *and* happen to be odd-sized. They are  either forced to use buffering which entails parasitic memory copies or suffer the penalty of doubling the amount of IOs to the file system. Neither option is sensible for any performance oriented code.

Comment: @Alf I think you are overestimating impatct of this one additional `ReadFile` call to transfer last byte on the end of file. A lot more time you will spend opening file, but this is not my code, so I don't feel need to defend it. P.S. I have implemented my own C++ IO librrary for some of my programs and is has real not bufered mode going stright to `ReadFile`.

Comment: @DanielSęk I think you may be missing my point: it's not an extra call at the end of the file, it's an extra kernel call for every odd-sized IO anywhere within the file. This does have a measurable performance impact, because it's 2 kernel calls instead of one.

Comment: @alf: Kernel calls are expensive, but nowhere near as expensive as reading from disk. You can rest assured, that the file I/O implementation will aggressively prefetch data from disk, when it observes sequential reads. Besides, when using an abstraction (like the CRT), you will inevitably have to pay. The cost can be anything from performance degradation to limited functionality. For example, `fread` has no equivalent to [ReadFileScatter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfilescatter). Just drop the abstraction if it doesn't meet your requirements.